# Allowing only numerical replies on jquery validate field

Tags: jquery, forms

How do you check that the user has put in only numerical values if you are using the jquery validate plugin on a field?

```
<script>   
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#form1").validate();}); 
</script>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" name="form1" id="form1" class="form1">
<input name="Capacity" type="text" id="Capacity" class="required">
<label for="Capacity" class="error">Please specify a capacity</label>
<input type="submit" name="Submit1" value="Search" id="Submit1" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [digits()](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/digits) rule or the [number()](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/number) rule if you want to allow decimals.

```
$("#form1").validate({
    rules: {
        Capacity: {
            digits: true
        }
    }
});
```